# S6478: Do not define components during render

Tags: reactjs, sonarqube

I need to create a [FluentUI DetailsList](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/detailslist) with a sticky header. The solution [DetailsList Fixed Header without ScrollablePane](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/scrollablepane) (funnily available on the ScrollablePane documentation page), does not work for me. I found instead [this option](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/issues/1146):

```
<ScrollablePane>
    <DetailsList
            items={items}
            ...
            onRenderDetailsHeader={
              (detailsHeaderProps: IDetailsHeaderProps, defaultRender: IRenderFunction<IDetailsHeaderProps>) => (
                <Sticky>
                  {defaultRender(detailsHeaderProps)}
                </Sticky>
              ) }
               />
</ScrollablePane>
```

But here SonarQube raises [warning S6478 (Do not define components during render)](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-unstable-nested-components.md).

Refactoring the value of `onRenderDetailsHeader` inside a constant method makes the problem go away:

```
const onRenderDetailsHeader = (detailsHeaderProps: IDetailsHeaderProps, defaultRender: IRenderFunction<IDetailsHeaderProps>): JSX.Element => {
    return <Sticky>
                {defaultRender(detailsHeaderProps)}
            </Sticky>
}
```

and

```
<DetailsList
    onRenderDetailsHeader={onRenderDetailsHeader}
    ...
```

But does this actually solve the problem? Does this actually prevent creating "new component type on every render and destroy the entire subtree's DOM nodes and state"?